# Writing Foreign Members to GeoJSON files using ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, geojson, ogr2ogr

I have a GeoJSON file, `example.geojson`:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "example",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -21.987, 64.208 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -21.012, 65.123 ] } }
]
}
```

I would like to add a Foreign Member to each feature. Foreign Members are described in [Section 6.1 of the RFC7946 specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#section-6.1). I can achieve this via [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/):

```
jq '.features |= map(. + {"foreign-key": "foreign-value"})' example.geojson > with_foreign_member.geojson
```

Result:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "name": "example",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    }
  },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -21.987,
          64.208
        ]
      },
      "foreign-key": "foreign-value"
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -21.012,
          65.123
        ]
      },
      "foreign-key": "foreign-value"
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem with this approach is that it does not work for large GeoJSONs, my `jq` command gets `Killed`. I generate the large GeoJSON file using `ogr2ogr`, so it would be nice if I could write the Foreign Members too, when I generate the file.

**How can I write Foreign Members to GeoJSON files using `ogr2ogr`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will be available in GDAL 3.9 per https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/pull/8830

```
ogr2ogr out.json in.whatever -lco "FOREIGN_MEMBERS_FEATURE={\"foreign-key\": \"foreign-value\"}"
```